# Eclipse Kepler: Hide specific items in Project Explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, buildpath, package-explorer

I'm using Eclipse Kepler and I'm unable to 1) hide the target folder and 2) to hide the duplicate src folder in project explorer.

[image: Project Explorer]

In previous versions it was possible to filter the folders with a regex, but in Kepler I don't see an option to enter a regex in Customize View->Filters.
I checked "Java output folders" and "Maven build folder" but they are still visible.

For the duplicate src folder:
I would like to only see the top one (the one with the flattened layout)

Here's my build path:

[image: Build Path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. Apparently the default view in Kepler is "Project Explorer". Switching to "Package Explorer" reveals the old functionality with the familiar "Filters" dialog. There I entered target,src et voila...

Comment: Note: If you have non-maven project in your workspace, the scr folder disappears and you won't see any source code ;)